# 2D matrix of matrices

Tags: matlab

I have two diagonal matrices. I am trying to build a larger block diagonal matrix from them.  For example if I had this:

```
D = diag(zeros(3,1)+1)

D =

     1     0     0
     0     1     0
     0     0     1
```

and...

```
E = diag(zeros(2,1)+2, -1) + diag(zeros(2,1)+2, +1) + diag(zeros(3,1)+4)

E =

     4     2     0
     2     4     2
     0     2     4
```

I have an equation that says A*U = X

Where A is

```
[E D 0

D E D

0 D E]
```

This is for 3x3.  5x5 would look like this:

```
A =

    [E D 0 0 0 

    D E D 0 0 

    0 D E D 0

    0 0 D E D

    0 0 0 D E]
```

A would be another diagonal matrix consisting of these matrices. I need to produce a 40x40 and it would take a VERY LONG TIME to do manually, of course.

How can I define that? I haven't figured out how to use blkdiag to construct.

Comment: How does `A` have 40 rows when `E` and `D` have only 3 ?

Comment: Have you tried `[E, D, zeros(size(E); D, E, D; zeros(size(E)), D, E]`?

Comment: @High Performance Mark - Right, so I explained poorly.  In my example all of them are 3x3.  In my real example, all of them are 40x40.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this on my own manually because I could never find a Matlab function to help me.

```
        for n = 1:Distance_Resolution
            A(((n-1)*Distance_Resolution +1):n*Distance_Resolution, ((n-1)*Distance_Resolution +1):n*Distance_Resolution) = A1;
            if n == Distance_Resolution
            else
                A((n*Distance_Resolution+1):(n+1)*(Distance_Resolution), ((n-1)*Distance_Resolution+1:n*Distance_Resolution)) = A2;
                A((n-1)*Distance_Resolution+1:n*Distance_Resolution, (n*Distance_Resolution+1):(n+1)*(Distance_Resolution)) = A2;
            end
        end
```

This will produce a block matrix that has the above specified demands and is of length Distance_Resolution x Distance_Resolution x Distance_Resolution.  I defined A1 and A2 through help from above poster (Fo is just a constant here):

```
vector = zeros(Distance_Resolution,1) - Fo;
A2 = diag(vector);
A1 = toeplitz([1+4*Fo, -Fo, zeros(1,Distance_Resolution-2)]);
```

This is a workable code snippet, but I am still looking for a smarter way to code it.